# EditText's not changing on ImageButton press?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am very new to coding so there could be all sorts of issues with this but after doing a fair bit of searching, I can't find whats wrong with it, I don't get any errors or crashes, the buttons just do nothing?

The aim is to have the orange arrows increase and decrease the number in the middle by 1.

***App Screenshot:***

[image: App Screenshot]

I don't know what code to show you so here is most of it:

**T3_TrampetFragment.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class T3_TrampetFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.t3_trampetlayout, container, false);
        }
}
```

**t3_trampetlayout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".T3_TrampetFragment">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblrow_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Tariff Calculator"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblrow_rotations"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_rotations"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Rotations"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_r_minus"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
                android:foregroundTint="@color/colorSecondary"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                android:rotation="180" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Rnum"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/sRnum"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorControlNormal"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_r_plus"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
                android:foregroundTint="@color/colorSecondary"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblrow_pike"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_pike"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Pike Bonus"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_p_minus"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
                android:foregroundTint="@color/colorSecondary"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                android:rotation="180" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Pnum"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/sPnum"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorControlNormal"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_p_plus"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
                android:foregroundTint="@color/colorSecondary"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblrow_straight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_straight"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Straight Bonus"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_s_minus"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
                android:foregroundTint="@color/colorSecondary"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                android:rotation="180" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Snum"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/sSnum"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorControlNormal"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_s_plus"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
                android:foregroundTint="@color/colorSecondary"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblrow_twist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_twist"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Twists"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_t_minus"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
                android:foregroundTint="@color/colorSecondary"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                android:rotation="180" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Tnum"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/sTnum"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorControlNormal"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_t_plus"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
                android:foregroundTint="@color/colorSecondary"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblrow_result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_result"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Difficulty"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/_space"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorSecondary"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Resultnum"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/sResultnum"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorControlNormal"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/_space2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorSecondary"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**T3_TrampetActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class T3_TrampetActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageButton BtnRMinus, BtnRPlus, BtnPMinus, BtnPPlus, BtnSMinus, BtnSPlus, BtnTMinus, BtnTPlus;
    EditText R_num, P_num, S_num, T_num, Result_num;
    int R_counter = (1);
    int P_counter, S_counter = (0);
    double T_counter = (0.0);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.t3_trampetlayout);

        R_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Rnum);
        P_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Pnum);
        S_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Snum);
        T_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tnum);
        Result_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Resultnum);

        BtnRMinus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_r_minus);
        BtnRPlus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_r_plus);
        BtnPMinus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_p_minus);
        BtnPPlus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_p_plus);
        BtnSMinus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_s_minus);
        BtnSPlus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_s_plus);
        BtnTMinus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_t_minus);
        BtnTPlus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_t_plus);

        BtnRMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnRPlus.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnPMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnPPlus.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnSMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnSPlus.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnTMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnTPlus.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_r_minus:

                if (R_counter > 1) {
                    --R_counter;
                    R_num.setText(String.valueOf(R_counter));
                }

                break;
            case R.id.btn_r_plus:

                if (R_counter < 3) {
                    ++R_counter;
                    R_num.setText(String.valueOf(R_counter));
                }

                break;
            case R.id.btn_p_minus:

                if (P_counter > 0) {
                    --P_counter;
                    P_num.setText(String.valueOf(P_counter));
                }

                break;
            case R.id.btn_p_plus:

                if (P_counter < 3) {
                    ++P_counter;
                    P_num.setText(String.valueOf(P_counter));
                }

                break;
            case R.id.btn_s_minus:

                if (S_counter > 0) {
                    --S_counter;
                    S_num.setText(String.valueOf(S_counter));
                }

                break;
            case R.id.btn_s_plus:

                if (S_counter < 3) {
                    ++S_counter;
                    S_num.setText(String.valueOf(S_counter));
                }

                break;
            case R.id.btn_t_minus:

                if (T_counter > 0) {
                    T_counter = (T_counter - 0.5);
                    T_num.setText(String.valueOf(T_counter));
                }

                break;
            case R.id.btn_t_plus:

                if (T_counter < 5.5) {
                    T_counter = (T_counter + 0.5);
                    T_num.setText(String.valueOf(T_counter));
                }

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">TG Mobile</string>
    <string name="in_app_name">TeamGym Mobile</string>
    <string name="sRnum">1</string>
    <string name="sPnum">0</string>
    <string name="sSnum">0</string>
    <string name="sTnum">0.0</string>
    <string name="sResultnum">0.00</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: I Just copy and Paste your code it's working as you want but here I Use Only Your Activity and layout (with remove line tools:context=".T3_TrampetFragment"). Not Added Fragment in my code (B'coz I don´t find any reason to use a fragment in your code). So check with removing fragment from your code.

Comment: In it's current form, it's going to be pretty hard for someone to answer your question. We don't know if you ever had it working before, but then maybe you changed one thing and the buttons stopped working. This is important information.

I think your best bet is to find some sample code for Android that creates a *very* simple app, such as one button that updates one counter. Run the sample, then make small changes. (e.g. two counters, two buttons) If that change doesn't work, ask for help on *that* problem. The code will be much smaller and people will be much more likely to answer.

Comment: @Janak The fragment is for the tabs to work across the top to work, or at least it thought that was the only way?

Comment: @Connor First Call Fragment from Activity and Write this code in Fragment Class.

Comment: @Janak Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: @Connor : Check the Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create T3_TrampetActivity like this And Call Your Fragment from Activity:

```
public class T3_TrampetActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Fragment fragment = new  T3_TrampetFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }
}
```

Create activity_main.xml as like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                
             android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"            
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Update T3_TrampetFragment.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class T3_TrampetFragment extends Fragment  implements View.OnClickListener {


ImageButton BtnRMinus, BtnRPlus, BtnPMinus, BtnPPlus, BtnSMinus, BtnSPlus, BtnTMinus, BtnTPlus;
EditText R_num, P_num, S_num, T_num, Result_num;
int R_counter = (1);
int P_counter, S_counter = (0);
double T_counter = (0.0);

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.t3_trampetlayout, container, false);



    R_num = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Rnum);
    P_num = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Pnum);
    S_num = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Snum);
    T_num = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Tnum);
    Result_num = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Resultnum);

    BtnRMinus = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_r_minus);
    BtnRPlus = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_r_plus);
    BtnPMinus = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_p_minus);
    BtnPPlus = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_p_plus);
    BtnSMinus = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_s_minus);
    BtnSPlus = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_s_plus);
    BtnTMinus = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_t_minus);
    BtnTPlus = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_t_plus);

    BtnRMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
    BtnRPlus.setOnClickListener(this);
    BtnPMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
    BtnPPlus.setOnClickListener(this);
    BtnSMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
    BtnSPlus.setOnClickListener(this);
    BtnTMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
    BtnTPlus.setOnClickListener(this);

  return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_r_minus:

            if (R_counter > 1) {
                --R_counter;
                R_num.setText(String.valueOf(R_counter));
            }

            break;
        case R.id.btn_r_plus:

            if (R_counter < 3) {
                ++R_counter;
                R_num.setText(String.valueOf(R_counter));
            }

            break;
        case R.id.btn_p_minus:

            if (P_counter > 0) {
                --P_counter;
                P_num.setText(String.valueOf(P_counter));
            }

            break;
        case R.id.btn_p_plus:

            if (P_counter < 3) {
                ++P_counter;
                P_num.setText(String.valueOf(P_counter));
            }

            break;
        case R.id.btn_s_minus:

            if (S_counter > 0) {
                --S_counter;
                S_num.setText(String.valueOf(S_counter));
            }

            break;
        case R.id.btn_s_plus:

            if (S_counter < 3) {
                ++S_counter;
                S_num.setText(String.valueOf(S_counter));
            }

            break;
        case R.id.btn_t_minus:

            if (T_counter > 0) {
                T_counter = (T_counter - 0.5);
                T_num.setText(String.valueOf(T_counter));
            }

            break;
        case R.id.btn_t_plus:

            if (T_counter < 5.5) {
                T_counter = (T_counter + 0.5);
                T_num.setText(String.valueOf(T_counter));
            }

            break;
        default:
            break;
      }
    }
}
```

t3_trampetlayout.xml Use same layou for Fragment.